# Indexing numpy array with index array of lower dim yields array of higher dim than both

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
a = np.zeros((5,4,3))
v = np.ones((5, 4), dtype=int)
data = a[v]
shp = data.shape
```

This code gives `shp==(5,4,4,3)`

I don't understand why. How can a larger array be output? makes no sense to me and would love an explanation.

Comment: Think of `a[v]` as `a[v, :, :]`.  The `v` index applies only to the first dimension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). Advanced indexing allows you to select arbitrary elements in the input array based on an N-dimensional index.

Let's use another example to make it clearer:

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 5, (5,4,3))
v = np.ones((5, 4), dtype=int)
```

Say in this case `a` is:

```
array([[[2, 1, 1],
        [3, 4, 4],
        [4, 3, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[4, 4, 1],
        [3, 3, 4],
        [3, 4, 2],
        [1, 3, 1]],

       [[3, 1, 3],
        [4, 3, 1],
        [2, 1, 4],
        [1, 2, 2]],
        ...
```

By indexing with an array of `np.ones`:

```
print(v)

array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

You will simply be indexing `a` with `1` along the first axis as many times as `v`. Putting it in another way, when you do:

```
a[1]

[[4, 4, 1],
 [3, 3, 4],
 [3, 4, 2],
 [1, 3, 1]]
```

You're indexing along the first axis, as no indexing is specified along the additional axes. It is the same as doing `a[1, ...]`, i.e taking a full slice along the remaining axes. Hence by indexing with a `2D` array of ones, you will have the above `2D` array `(5, 4)` times stacked together, resulting in an ndarray of shape `(5, 4, 4, 3)`. Or in other words, `a[1]`, of shape `(4,3)`, stacked `5*4=20` times.

Hence, in this case you'd be getting:

```
array([[[[4, 4, 1],
         [3, 3, 4],
         [3, 4, 2],
         [1, 3, 1]],

        [[4, 4, 1],
         [3, 3, 4],
         [3, 4, 2],
         [1, 3, 1]],
         ...
```

Comment: I got here again, this time from the other side. How can I index an array of shape (5, 4, 3) with an array of shape (4, 3) at [:, ind_array] and get an array of shape (4, 3)?

Answer (score 0):

the value of `v` is:

```
[[1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

every single `1` indexes a complete "row" in `a`, but every "element" in said "row" is a matrix. so every "row" in `v` indexes a "row" of "matrix"es in `a`.
(does this make any sense to you..?)

so you get 5 * 4 `1`s, each is a 4*3 "matrix".

if instead of `zeroes` you define `a` as `a = np.arange(5*4*3).reshape((5, 4, 3))`
it might be easier to understand, because you get to see which parts of `a` are being chosen:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5*4*3).reshape((5, 4, 3))
v = np.ones((5,4), dtype=int)
data = a[v]
print(data)
```

(output is pretty long, I don't want to paste it here)